# Switching between Chrome Developer Tools and main window full screen

Tags: google-chrome, fullscreen

I'm running OS X 10.5.5 Yosemite. What's the shortcut to switch between Chrome Developer Tools (Cmd + Alt + J) and the main Chrome browser window, when both are full screen?

Cmd + ` doesn't work.

The Developer tools seems to register as another instance of Chrome running, so Application switching doesn't work either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Mission Control (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>) to drag the main Chrome window and the DevTools window to adjacent *spaces*, if they are not already next to each other. You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to cycle through spaces.

Mac users will generally keep all related spaces adjacent to each other, in a group, and use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> to navigate between them.

Comment: I come from windows background and I am used to alt + tab. Having hard time due to this issue. This is useful though will take time to get used to.

Comment: Also, if I use cmd+tab by mistake, it moves chrome and dev tools away from each other and I have to rearrange them again.